# Bootstrap 4 Modal centered with automatic width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a BootStrap 4 Modal centered in the screen. I know that this is possible using class "modal-dialog-centered". The thing is that I also need a modal with variable width - a width that adjust the modal to the content. I am struggling with this problem. I have already tried container fluid approach, css approach and others. Since I am not an expert with all these tools, I kindly ask for suggestions.

This is my current modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="modal_{{ forloop.counter }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="snapshotmodal" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Snapshot:</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-auto">
                              <h4>{{ alert.title }} </h4><br><br>
                              {{ alert.data|safe }}  
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap modal is actually a `flexbox` component. So you can easily manipulate it:

```css
.modal {
  /* Styles to make the modal visible */
  display: flex !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.modal-dialog {
  justify-content: center !important;
}

.modal-content {
  width: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_{{ forloop.counter }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="snapshotmodal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Snapshot:</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-auto">
              <h4>{{ alert.title }} </h4><br><br>
              {{ alert.data|safe }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implmented your code, but now the modal is always on the screen. It is not following the expected behavior. In other words, the modal should appear after the button click, but now it is permanently on screen. Do you know what it's happening? Thanks again.

Comment: @JoaoSalles Thats normal because I hadded styles to make it appear. Just remove all my styles for `.modal` ;)

Comment: It is working for my data like a charm. But I don't know why the string (the alert.title in my code) is still overflowing the modal. Do you know what this can possibly be? Thanks again!

Comment: @JoaoSalles That strange because even with a huge title the modal expand. See an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zw5pbjhg/4/). With the current data I won't be able to help you.